# phpunit is running a TestCase class

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I am using phpunit to unit test a project, and have a class called StdTestCase in the root of the tests that is a superclass for all the test classes.

Out of the blue, phpunit started to try running this class a test class, and I get this warning

```
1) Warning
No tests found in class "std\tests\StdTestCase".
```

My config file is present in the root of the project, which is where I run the tests from, with this content.

**/phpunit.xml**

```
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         syntaxCheck="true"
         bootstrap="./std/tests/bootstrap.php"
        >
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="StdTestSuite">
            <directory>./std/tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mark your superclass as abstract, because it clearly is supposed to be.

Comment: This did fix the issue, but it seems that there is some underlying issue that is not being fixed. Should php not ignore every file that does not end with *Test.php* ?